# Delete mesh layers

Tags: python, mesh

How can I delete a member of `object.data.polygon_layers_float`?

I only see a `.new()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's missing. Poke a developer to add the remove function for Mesh(ID).

You can delete it using bmesh, but it is pretty cumbersome.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

layer = bm.faces.layers.float[layer_name]
bm.faces.layers.float.remove(layer)

bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
mesh.update()
```

Comment: Wonderful. It works. It's awkward, but it's easy enough to enclose it in a function.